# Pass data from Model to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with a list of data and my View accesses the model properties and renders the database status. There are several boxes in my view which displays color according to their respective values in the database. And each div corresponds to one item in the database.

I know I haven't coded my View in a correct way but it is what I want my view to look like (each div ID corresponding to the respective boxID in the database and displaying its respective color). And I want 500 database values represented in the View.

```
@model List<My.Namespace.BoxStatusModel>

<table>
    <tr class="first">
        <td class="dclass1">    
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="top @boxStatus.Color">
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="top @boxStatus.Color">
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="bottom @boxStatus.Color">
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="bottom @boxStatus.Color">
        </td>
        <td class="dclass2">    
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="top @boxStatus.Color">
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="top @boxStatus.Color">
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="bottom @boxStatus.Color">
            <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="bottom @boxStatus.Color">
        </td>
        ...          
    </tr>
    <tr class="second">
    ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

My Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MySQL msql = new MySQL();                          
        List<List<string>> results = msql.SelectTable("Select boxID, boxStatus from BoxStatusModel");
        List<BoxStatusModel> model = new List<BoxStatusModel>();    

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
                model.Add(new BoxStatusModel()
                {
                    slotID = results[i][0],
                    currentStatus = results[i][1]
                });
        } 
        return View(model);
    }        
}
```

My ViewModel

```
namespace My.ViewModels
{
    public class BoxStatusModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string boxID { get; set; }

        public string boxStatus { get; set; }

        public string Color
        {
            get
            {
                switch (boxStatus)
                {
                    case "busy":
                    return "red";

                    case "available":
                    return "green";

                    default:
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What exactly are you having trouble with? Do you have any errors -- what error are you getting?

Comment: Since my model is a List, I cannot write the following in my View without using a for loop.

    <div id="@boxStatus.boxID" class="top @boxStatus.Color">

And if I use a for loop, the view is not displayed as I want it to be.

Comment: You can use an index and write each element out if you don't want a loop: `id="@Model[0].boxID" class="top @Model[0].Color"`. If `@Model` bothers you then reassign it `@{ var boxStatus = Model; }`

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.